# Writing numbers on the top of the matrix as shown in figure

Tags: beamer, matrices

I'm trying to write numbers on a matrix as shown in the figure. Please help in this issue. Thank you so much for your time.[image]

Comment: try with `bordermatrix`. it is designed for such cases.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with `blockarray`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blkarray, bigstrut}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\[ \bigstrutjot=5pt
X = \begin{blockarray}{*{7}{c}}
& 1 & 2 & \dots & j & \dots &n \\
  \begin{block}{r[*{6}{c}]}%
    1 & & & & & & \bigstrut[t]\\
    2 & & & & & & \\
    \vdots & & & & & & \\
    i & & & & & & \\
    \vdots & & & & & & \\
    m & & & & & & \bigstrutjot = 3pt\bigstrut[b]\\
  \end{block}\
  \end{blockarray} \]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]